# Simple Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a simple bootstrap  carousel for my website. I found the above code. However the CSS height of carousel seems to be the issue. The CODE is the same code from the EXAMPLE on the website below:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=carousel

What I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Carousel</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.carousel{
    background: #2f4357;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.carousel .item img{
    margin: 0 auto; /* Align slide image horizontally center */
}
.bs-example{
 margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   
        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="../images/slide1.png" alt="First Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../images/slide2.png" alt="Second Slide">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="../images/slide3.png" alt="Third Slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel controls -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Help? I don't understand why it looks like this?

Comment: What's the problem that you're having? It appears as I would expect.

Comment: It's working? what's your problem? https://jsfiddle.net/sdc9cpga/

Comment: The only problem I can think of here is that may be the images are not present at the specified path.

Comment: When I run the snippet, The height of the banner is incorrect. I said width I mean height. I'll correct that. Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing.https://s32.postimg.org/w7bz6k0at/Stackoverflow_code_heighissue.png . Here is what it should look like: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=carousel

Comment: @BenjaminJones As I mentioned earlier, the image path you specified is incorrect. Check in firebug if the images are getting loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Images were not define: 
jsfiddle.net/sdc9cpga

Answer (score 0):

The carousel height is determined by an image, with your code, I added an image in the path and it worked fine. Otherwise add a defined height here: .carousel-inner > .item > img